# Bundler can't find Nokogiri installed with dnf package on Fedora

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, fedora

I'm trying to move a working Rails 4 application to a Fedora24 production system where I cannot compile.

I tried to install the "difficult" packages like ruby-sqlite3, nokogiri, json via the dnf package manager because Fedora provides up-to-date packages of these. However, after installing rubygem-nokogiri-1.6.8-3 on my Fedora system, bundle can't find it, it says:

```
$ bundle install
Using rake 11.1.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0221
Using arel 6.0.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.1
Using multi_json 1.11.3
Using bundler 1.12.5
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using spring 1.7.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using sprockets 3.6.0
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using activesupport 4.2.6
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activemodel 4.2.6
Using jbuilder 2.4.1
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using activejob 4.2.6
Using activerecord 4.2.6
Using actionview 4.2.6
Using actionpack 4.2.6
Using actionmailer 4.2.6
Using railties 4.2.6
Using sprockets-rails 3.0.4
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using rails 4.2.6
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using web-console 2.3.0
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Updating files in vendor/cache
Could not find nokogiri-1.6.8.gem for installation
```

While gem seems to be able to find it:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.6)
actionpack (4.2.6)
actionview (4.2.6)
activejob (4.2.6)
activemodel (4.2.6)
activerecord (4.2.6)
activesupport (4.2.6)
arel (6.0.3)
bigdecimal (1.2.8)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.12.5)
coffee-rails (4.1.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
jbuilder (2.4.1)
jquery-rails (4.1.1)
json (1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.4)
mime-types (3.0)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0221)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (5.8.4)
multi_json (1.11.3)
nokogiri (1.6.8)
psych (2.0.17)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.6)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (4.2.6)
rake (11.1.2)
rdoc (4.2.2)
sass (3.4.22)
sass-rails (5.0.4)
sdoc (0.4.1)
spring (1.7.1)
sprockets (3.6.0)
sprockets-rails (3.0.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.2)
turbolinks (2.5.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
uglifier (3.0.0)
web-console (2.3.0)
```

My Gemfile:

```
$ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

## Use Puma as the app server
###gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

#group :development, :test do
#  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
#  gem 'byebug'
#end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: could you also add your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Added my Gemfile above

Comment: Why is the bundle command output, gem command output, and Gemfile so inconsistent?

Comment: Could it be because I <snipped> parts away? Did it in multiple runs, but I'll run all three sequentially tonight and update the output.

Comment: Also, I've installed most of the packages ((all those not requiring compiling) ) locally from cache/vendor using bundler install --local. However the output doesn't change while using or not using the --local flag.

Comment: Updated as you requested Matt. Does this change anything?

Comment: What is the output of `gem env`? Also, in my experience, it's MUCH easier to install Ruby from source and compile it than to rely on the repos. And/or, use rbenv or RVM to manage a Ruby for that application's owning ID.